# Is it possible to read-write the memory of a Gikfun ISD1820 voice recording module?

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi, audio, memory, speaker

I just got a Gikfun ISD1820 voice recording module for an Arduino project that I'm working on. I want to be able to record a few seconds message and then send the message over wifi to another Arduino Mega 2560, which will then play back the message.

The ISD1820 module can record and play back short messages and can be controlled from the Arduino, but I want to know if it is possible to access the memory / read-write the memory of the ISD1820 module to accomplish my goal. And how would I do it?

If it is impossible, what hardware should I get instead? Do I need a wave shield with a SD card or a wifi shield with an SD card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't. That module can only record and play.

The only possible thing you could do is record onto the chip then play it back recording it on to the Arduino (at ridiculously low quality) - in which case, what would the point of the chip be?

If you want some quality to your recordings you need a powerful microcontroller with an I2S interface and a CODEC chip.  However any powerful MCU (such as the ARM chip on the Due, or the Teensy, or the PIC32 chip on the chipKIT boards) can sample at a reasonable quality through the ADC inputs.

The Arduino Uno can record very short bursts at very low quality (due to lack of memory) without any external hardware (except a suitable microphone preamplifier). The Mega can record slightly more, but the quality will still be very low.